# iOS Swift SlideMenuControllerSwift

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning to develop iOS and come across to this awesome library [SlideMenuController](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SlideMenuControllerSwift). I am able to make use of this library to create awesome slide menu easily.

However, there are some problem that I am facing during implementing with this library.

**Environment**

In my project storyboard, I have 1 TabBarViewController and 2 ViewController which is under this TabBarViewController. I also have 2 independent ViewController which are LoginViewController and LeftMenuViewController.

I have below code in my AppDelegate.swift file

```
    ...
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
        let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftMenuViewController") as! LeftMenuViewController


        let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: mainViewController, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)

        SlideMenuOptions.contentViewScale = 1
        SlideMenuOptions.hideStatusBar = false;

        self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
    ...
```

Everything work perfectly if I don't need my login view as a initial view. I notice that this line of code **self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController** will always make sure that view in mainViewController to be the initial view when the app open.

How can I have my LoginView as the initial view when my app start up and the slide menu is still bind to the TabBarViewController and working properly?

I have try to move the code from AppDelegate.swift to viewDidLoad() function in TabBarViewController.swift but no luck. It is not working.

Need some guilds and help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code instead of yours :

var window: UIWindow?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
    let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftMenuViewController") as! LeftMenuViewController
    let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

    let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
    leftViewController.mainVC = nvc
    let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: nvc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)

    SlideMenuOptions.contentViewScale = 1
    SlideMenuOptions.hideStatusBar = false;

    self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

dont forget to add this variable in your LeftMenuViewController

var mainVC : UIViewController!